# How to create custom ACL functionality in Django 2.x?

Tags: python-3.x, acl, django-2.1, custom-authentication

I want to create custom ACl functionality in Django2.x

Acl project structure below:

```
C->Company
R->Role (superuser, admin, manager etc.)
U->User

C1->r1,r2,r3->u1,u2,u3,u4,u5
C2->r1,r2,r3->u6,u7,u8,u9,u10
C3->r1,r2,r3->u11,u12,u13,u15,u15
```

How can i give the permission user to role wise for multiple company?

Can i customize to default auth-model?